# Поправить аккордеон, на мобайл версии клик, на десктопной mouseenter

Tags: javascript

Есть аккордеон, на ПК должен открываться на mouseenter на мобайле через клик, не могу организовать код :(
На пк все работает ок, но на мобильных устройствах открывается со второго клика, подскажите как решить проблему.

```
https://codepen.io/artur-alexandrowich/pen/XWjwXgy
```

```js
// ПК

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
}


function ready() {
  let accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item-header");
  for (let i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
    accordion[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      accordionMouseenter(event);
    });
  }
  /// on load firs item in accordion opened
  let allDescriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item-body");
  let icon = document.querySelectorAll('.item_header-icon')
  icon[0].classList.toggle('close_icon')
  allDescriptions[0].style.maxHeight = allDescriptions[0].scrollHeight + "px";
  /// end  firs item in accordion opened
}


let accordionMouseenter = (eventHappened) => {
  let allDescriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item-body");

  for (let i = 0; i < allDescriptions.length; i++) {
    if (allDescriptions[i].style.maxHeight) {
      allDescriptions[i].style.maxHeight = null;
      allDescriptions[i].parentNode.classList.remove('acordion_active')
    }
  }
  let targetEnterMouse = event.target;
  let classEnter = targetEnterMouse.classList;

  while ((classEnter[0] != "accordion-item-header")) {
    targetEnterMouse = targetEnterMouse.parentElement;
    classEnter = targetEnterMouse.classList;
  }
  let description = targetEnterMouse.nextElementSibling;

  if (description.style.maxHeight) {
    description.style.maxHeight = null;

  } else {
    description.style.maxHeight = description.scrollHeight + "px";
    description.parentNode.classList.add('acordion_active')
  }
}

//  ПК



//mobile
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-item-header ')

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling


    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      this.classList.remove('open_acc')
      this.getElementsByClassName('item_header-icon')[0].classList.remove('close_icon')
      panel.parentNode.classList.remove('acordion_active')
    } else {


      for (let x = 0; x < acc.length; x++) {
        acc[x].classList.remove('open_acc')
        acc[x].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
        acc[x].getElementsByClassName('item_header-icon')[0].classList.remove('close_icon')
        panel.parentNode.classList.remove('acordion_active')
      }
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
      this.classList.toggle('open_acc')
      this.getElementsByClassName('item_header-icon')[0].classList.add('close_icon')
      panel.parentNode.classList.add('acordion_active')
    }
  })
}

// mobile
```

```css
.sell_accordion {
  padding: 20px 0 120px 20px;
  width: 75%;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion {
  width: 100%;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-header {
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 59px;
  color: black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-header:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-header.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6C00;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-body {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-body .accordion-item-body-content {
  padding: 0 0 50px 0px;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-body .accordion-item-body-content p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.sell_accordion .accordion_content .accordion .accordion-item .accordion-item-body .accordion-item-body-content p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell_accordion">
  <div class="accordion_content">
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Мы продаем
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aspernatur non voluptates adipisci sapiente architecto, quod temporibus blanditiis fugit praesentium.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, aspernatur.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae voluptates nisi, dolorem esse ut placeat autem dolorum, quia in beatae non praesentium enim quis et sunt aperiam cum eius voluptatem a voluptate optio quibusdam maiores? Amet corporis
              eos iusto error beatae similique molestias, reiciendis consequuntur, quae quaerat aspernatur sit qui.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Мы доставляем
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Аренда полей и предзаказ урожая
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
            <p>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quae fuga cumque similique deserunt quisquam. Culpa accusantium eum animi et!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Овощи и фрукты. Что-нибудь еще?
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
            <p>
              HTTP, aka HyperText Transfer Protocol, is the underlying protocol used by the World Wide Web and this protocol defines how messages are formatted and transmitted, and what actions Web servers and browsers should take in response to various commands.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Нужен представитель в Турции:
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
            <p>
              CORS, aka Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, is a mechanism that enables many resources (e.g. images, stylesheets, scripts, fonts) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-item-header">
          Работа с контрагентами
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item-body">
          <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
            <p>
              CORS, aka Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, is a mechanism that enables many resources (e.g. images, stylesheets, scripts, fonts) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```